# How can i make my TimerAction to work? (Windows Form Application)

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I'm working at a Windows Forms application and i need to use timers.
I have this method to set the timer in order to do something at a certain time:

```
      private void SetTimerValue()
    {
        // trigger the event at 7 AM. For 7 PM use 19 i.e. 24 hour format

       // Console.Read();
        DateTime requiredTime = DateTime.Today.AddHours(7).AddMinutes(00);
        if (DateTime.Now > requiredTime)
        {
            requiredTime = requiredTime.AddDays(1);
        }

        // initialize timer only, do not specify the start time or the interval
        myTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(TimerAction));
        // first parameter is the start time and the second parameter is the interval
        // Timeout.Infinite means do not repeat the interval, only start the timer
        myTimer.Change((int)(requiredTime - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds, Timeout.Infinite);
    }
```

And this is the TimerAction:

```
     private void TimerAction(object e)
    {


            // do some work with my webcam(start recording)
            // now, call the set timer method to reset its next call time
    SetTimerValue();
    }
```

I call SetTimerValue() in my Form (Form1):

```
     public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        SetTimerValue();


    }
```

But after I run the application and timer reaches his time, the application closes.
It's something with my TimerAction method and with the parameters (object e) ?

The same action of the TimerAction I have it in a button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e) and it works.
Can you help me? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [right timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx), i.e. one that will be executed on the UI thread.